# Bridge between JavaPOS, POS for .NET and OPOS

Tags: javapos, pos-for-.net

I'm currently developing virtual devices as Service Objects (in terms of UnifiedPOS) which are intended to work under Windows, Linux (and probably other systems). The language used for them is Java (because of existing JavaPOS, and being cross-platform).

The solution is proxying SO methods invocations from thin platform-specific SO (lets call it client) to actual SO implementation -- server. Currently I'm looking forward to use Google's protocol buffers, but it makes me implement both sides on my own.

**The question**: Is there some already existing solution for that?

Anything that can split SO from CO across network will go.

<sub>Thanks in advance.</sub>

Comment: Did you ever find a bridge?

Comment: @HairOfTheDog No, I used to try, but failed. I stayed upon JavaPOS-only solution that moment, and I don't work on this project anymore (now).